# Disable ripple effect on element

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I'd like to disable the ripple effect on an `ion-chip` element, which fires on click:

```
<ion-chip>
   <ion-label>Hey</ion-label>
</ion-chip>
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: AFAIK `<ion-chip disableRipple>Hey</ion-chip>` could possibly work?

Comment: `your-element ion-button-effect {
  display: none;
}`

Comment: @KarlChelton didn't work.

Comment: @window.document neither.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
<ion-chip style="pointer-events: none;" >
```

that will disable the styling click event in the component. 
Assuming you want a click event you could put a div around it.

Comment: To allow clicking on a child element you could also use `pointer-events: initial` on the child element. I've set up helper classes for this purpose: 
```.no-click {
  pointer-events: none;
}```
 and 
```.yes-click {
  pointer-events: initial;
}
```

Comment: This will remove the ripple/click effect and make the element not clickable and if you make the child element clickable you will get the ripple effect back. You may want to try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/63032872/5151355

Answer (score 1):

please try this code to remove ripple effect

```
ion-chip.button-effect {
     display:none !important;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The Ripple effect is only present for the Android platform as per the [source code](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/981cb5674bb0c2ccaedb089e4a5b3c124a0ac588/core/src/components/chip/chip.tsx#L44). So, as a workaround, we can change the mode to `mode="ios"` to avoid the effect. There seems to be no other style difference in `ion-chip` amongst both the platforms.

Also, this would not mess up the existing `pointer-events`.

```
<ion-chip mode="ios">
  <ion-label>Hey </ion-label>
</ion-chip>
```

*Credits:* Inspired by [@rtpharry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/156388/rtpharry)'s answer to an alike [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58362117/5544970).