# How to remove click effect of an ion-item

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I want to remove click effect of an ion-item.I used --background-activated and --ripple-color but nothing happend.

```
.no-click{
--background-activated: transparent;
--ripple-color: transparent;
}

<ion-item class="no-click">
<ion-avatar slot="start">
<img [src]="img">
</ion-avatar>
<ion-label>{{name}}</ion-label>
</ion-item>
```

How can i remove click effect of an ion-item?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply give pointer-events:none css to disable click.

```
 .no-click {
   pointer-events:none; //This makes it not clickable
 }


<ion-item class="no-click">
    <ion-avatar slot="start">
        <img [src]="img">
        </ion-avatar>
     <ion-label>{{name}}</ion-label>
  </ion-item>
```

Comment: This will remove the ripple/click effect and make the element not clickable. This is ok if there is no controls inside ion-item that you want to keep receiving click events

Answer (score 7):

I would apply **no-ripple** class to ion-item and add the below styling

```
.no-ripple {
    --ripple-color: transparent;
    --background-activated: transparent;
}
```

This will remove ripple effect but will keep the element clickable. For example, you can have ion-checkbox inside ion-item and pointer-events:none; will prevent from clicking on it which might not be the behaviour that you need.

Comment: The question states the user has already done this, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 4):

This actually Works!

```
--ripple-color: transparent;
--background-activated: transparent;
--background-activated-opacity:transparent;
--background-focused: transparent;
--background-focused-opacity:transparent;
--background-hover  : transparent;
--background-hover-opacity  :transparent;
```

Comment: Perfect thanks!  This properly removes the "ripple" effect while still allowing for click events on the ion-item itself.  I'm surprised there isn't a property or utility class in ionic's framework already for this.