# How do I disable/remove ion-ripple effect in ion-button Ioinic 4?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I need to disable the default `ion-ripple-effect` in the `ion-button'.

```
<ion-button>
  <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="star"></ion-icon>
</ion-button>
```

[image]

I can't disable the `pointer-events` as I need it.

PS: I've referred the following posts and could not find a proper solution for Ionic 4.

1. [How to remove click effect of an ion-item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57751394/how-to-remove-click-effect-of-an-ion-item)
2. [Disable ripple effect on element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55865732/disable-ripple-effect-on-element)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`--ripple-color` CSS variable could be used to turn off the ripple effect.

```
 <ion-button class="no-ripple">
   <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="trash"></ion-icon>
 </ion-button>
```

For example, we could set `--ripple-color: transparent` on the button, to effectively disable the effect.

```
.no-ripple {
  --ripple-color: transparent;
}
```

Refer https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/19648

Comment: It doesn't turn off the ripple effect, it just makes it transparent. For example the margins are still there.

Comment: Yes. That's true. There was no official way to turn it off. This was the sort of recommended solution at that time. Do check the Github issue linked.

Answer (score 4):

Just set mode to iOS

```
<ion-button mode='ios'>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's only included with Android so you can set `mode="ios"` on the button to avoid that effect.

Yeah so I just [checked the source code](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/core/src/components/button/button.tsx#L227) and it is only used with `mode="md"` (which is Android / Material Design):

```
    <TagType
      {...attrs}
      class="button-native"
      disabled={disabled}
      onFocus={this.onFocus}
      onBlur={this.onBlur}
    >
      <span class="button-inner">
        <slot name="icon-only"></slot>
        <slot name="start"></slot>
        <slot></slot>
        <slot name="end"></slot>
      </span>
      {mode === 'md' && <ion-ripple-effect type={this.rippleType}></ion-ripple-effect>}
    </TagType>
```

That is the only way to do it using the button itself, the `rippleType` only offers `bounded` or `unbounded`, not a way to disable it.

I'm not sure if the `ion-ripple-effect` can be hidden with css because of the web components encapsulation used in Ionic 4.

Comment: Web components encapsulation makes it tough. However, mode="ios" does the trick. Thanks :D

Comment: cool, please consider marking as answer if you are happy with it, so others don't waste their time visiting and reading resolved questions

Answer (score 0):

In current version on Ionic 4, this is working example:

```
<ion-button class="submit-btn">...</ion-button>

.submit-btn {
    --background: transparent;
    --background-hover: transparent !important;
}
```

https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/button#css-custom-properties